# How might I simulate a backspace action in a text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

When a button is pressed, I simply want to simulate a "backspace" in a regular text box, deleting the character to the left of the cursor.

Google and various forums are producing really random results on this. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Im not sure it can be done that way, since the textfield will lose focus when pressing the button, so how would you know where the cursor was. Except if you are tracing it while typing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I'm guessing that you don't mean to put focus on the text input to delete it.

There are a couple of methods you could try. First, get the current contents of the input and remove the last character, then put the modified string back. For example (this code should work):

```
var txt = $('#myinputtextbox');
txt.val(txt.val().slice(0, -1));
```

The other would be to use js to simulate the backspace character key being hit. You would need to focus on the input, move the cursor to the end of the line, and then trigger the character.

Comment: This is simple enough for most cases, but doesn't handle situations where the cursor is placed somewhere in the middle of the text range, or when text is selected.

Comment: This is not the good answer, it removes the last character in the input field but doesn't simulate backspace.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work in Safari (and probably Firefox too), but I haven't tested it in IE:

```
  function backspaceAtCursor(id)
  {
    var field = document.getElementById(id);

    if(field.selectionStart)
    {
      var startPos = field.selectionStart;
      var endPos = field.selectionEnd;

      if(field.selectionStart == field.selectionEnd)
      {
        field.value = field.value.substring(0, startPos - 1) + field.value.substring(endPos, field.value.length);

        field.focus(); 
        field.setSelectionRange(startPos - 1, startPos - 1); 
      }
      else
      {
        field.value = field.value.substring(0, startPos) + field.value.substring(endPos, field.value.length);

        field.focus(); 
        field.setSelectionRange(startPos, startPos); 
      }
    }
  }
```

Use: `backspaceAtCursor('elementid')`

Comment: The check `if(field.selectionStart)` will fail when either the `selectionStart` property is not implemented or `selectionStart` is zero. `selectionStart` will be zero whenever the first character is included in the selection, meaning that such selections can't be deleted. This can be fixed by replacing the check with `if(field.hasOwnProperty('selectionStart'))`.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Javascript implementation, onClick

```
var text = document.getElementById(myTxtBox).value;  
text = text.substr(0,text.length-1);
document.getElementById(myTxtBox).value = text;
```

Comment: That just removes the last character in the textbox, it doesn't remove the character to the left of the cursor.

Comment: ouch, i thought he wanted to simulate backspace in general.

Comment: That's exactly what he's trying to do ;-) But a Backspace doesn't delete the last character in a textbox, but the character left to the cursor ;-)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery plugin to simulate a backspace in a text field, works in IE, FF, Chrome (based on code from [here](http://alexking.org/blog/2003/06/02/inserting-at-the-cursor-using-javascript)).

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
backspaceAtCaret: function(){
  return this.each(function(i) {    

    if (document.selection) 
    {
        this.focus();
        sel = document.selection.createRange();
        if(sel.text.length > 0)
        {
            sel.text="";
        }
        else
        {
            sel.moveStart("character",-1);
            sel.text="";
        }
        sel.select();
    }
    else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == "0")
    { 
        var startPos = this.selectionStart;
        var endPos = this.selectionEnd;

        this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos-1) + this.value.substring(endPos, this.value.length);
        this.selectionStart = startPos-1;
        this.selectionEnd = startPos-1;
        this.focus();
    } 
    else 
    {
        this.value=this.value.substr(0,(this.value.length-1));
        this.focus();
    }
  })
}
});
```