# Inputting into a text box via buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard

I'm trying to make a keyboard thing so that I can click the buttons on a webpage corresponding to each letter on the keyboard and then have those letters appear in a text box! I'm sure this is really simple and I actually did something similar in university but I can't remember it and have no access to my uni files!

Basically what I have is this:

```
    <div align="center">

    <form name="keyboard">

    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="Input"></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="Q" name="keyQ" onClick="AddDigit('Q')"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="W" name="keyW" onClick="AddDigit('W')"></td>
      <td><button>E</button></td>
      <td><button>R</button></td>
      <td><button>T</button></td>
      <td><button>Y</button></td>
      <td><button>U</button></td>  
      <td><button>I</button></td>
      <td><button>O</button></td>
      <td><button>P</button></td>
     </tr>
    </table></div>
```

I removed all the other lines of code just to reduce space but you get the idea of how I'm doing it. I tried adding the < input type="button" > things for two of the letters but I have no idea if I'm on the right track because it's really difficult to find anything regarding html/java keyboards, only about calculators.

This is literally just for my boyfriend so that, as soon as this is working I can change the value of different letters to things like Morse code because he's interested in stuff like that and I'm interested in stuff like this, even if I do suck.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem. This would help others with similar problems find a solution easily.

Answer (score 1):

you have to define AddDigit function.

```
function AddDigit(digit){
    var val =document.getElementById('Input').value
    document.getElementById('Input').value=val + digit;
}
```

here is working example

https://jsfiddle.net/Shilpi/1tye1b9t/7/

Comment: Thank you! I'm just glad other people can do things or I'd be stuck!><

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do is remove the `<form>` tags, since you don't transfer data to a different page.
You have already defined that `AddDigit(x)` gets called on click of a button, that's good so far.
A function like `AddDigit`will also require a target so we need to set an ID on the text field:
`<input type="text" name="Input" id="textField">`
Now we just need to define `AddDigit(x)`:

```js
function AddDigit(key){
 var value = document.getElementById("textField").value;
 document.getElementById("textField").value = value + key;
 
}
```

```html
    <div align="center">

    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="Input" id="textField"></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="Q" name="keyQ" onClick="AddDigit('Q')"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="W" name="keyW" onClick="AddDigit('W')"></td>
      <td><button>E</button></td>
      <td><button>R</button></td>
      <td><button>T</button></td>
      <td><button>Y</button></td>
      <td><button>U</button></td>  
      <td><button>I</button></td>
      <td><button>O</button></td>
      <td><button>P</button></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

`AddDigit(key)` takes one parameter and adds it to the end of the current value of the text field with the ID of `textField`.
If i understood you correctly, this should be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a JS Function where you get the values of the buttons and append them to the text box but make sure that your **buttons have IDs**.

But first of all, you need to assign  IDs to your buttons.

```
<input type="button" value="Q" id = "keyQ" name="keyQ" onClick="AddDigit('Q')">
```

**AddDigit(digit) JS Function**

```
var str = document.getElementById('Input').value;    
document.getElementById('Input').setText(str + digit);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<table>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="button" value="Q" onclick="inputChar(this)"/>
      <input type="button" value="W" onclick="inputChar(this)"/>
      <input type="button" value="E" onclick="inputChar(this)"/>
      <input type="button" value="R" onclick="inputChar(this)"/>
      <input type="button" value="T" onclick="inputChar(this)"/>
      <input type="button" value="Y" onclick="inputChar(this)"/>
      <br/>
      <input id="myTextBox" type="text" />
      </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript function

```
inputChar= function(clickedBtn){
  var myTextBox = document.getElementById("myTextBox");
  myTextBox.value += clickedBtn.value;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/flyinggambit/wh2dtwxd/

I noticed that you have an unclosed form tag, is it missed or intentional ?, either way its not needed.

The basic logic is to keep a reference to button char in some attribute, in my code its kept as value

`value="Q"`.

Then the next step would be to call a common function on button's click and pass the button reference,
we achieve this by

`onclick="inputChar(this)" \\ this is the button you clicked`

Now we want to get the textbox reference, the easiest way is to attach an id to the textfield

`<input id="myTextBox" type="text" />`

Then in the function, we can get it by document.getElementById

`var myTextBox = document.getElementById("myTextBox");`

Now that we have all the references we can update the textbox value

`myTextBox.value += clickedBtn.value;`

Also you can [simulate backspace key on text input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039135/simulate-backspace-key-on-text-input-field)

Hope this helps

**Update:**

To enter a different value, we will have to modify the code slightly

Instead of keeping the char reference in `value="Q"`, we will need to keep it in some other attribute, so I decided to use a custom attribute called `morse="A"`

In the JS function, we will need to change the last line
Instead of fetching data from "value" attribute, we have to get it from "morse" attribute

`myTextBox.value += clickedBtn.getAttribute("morse");`

Here is another fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/flyinggambit/wh2dtwxd/1/

Comment: Thank you so much! For the backspace key especially!

Comment: Sorry to ask for extra help, but say I wanted to then change the code so that when I clicked, say, Q, the input field would show 5 or something? Could I just replace _this_ with _'5'_ or is there another way of doing it? Thanks!

Comment: No need to apologize, I don't mind answering as long as I know the answer. Replacing `this` with `5` will break the code. If we had replaced it then, in the JS function, clickedBtn will be 5, that means we cannot use it to get any attribute. This would force us to use some alternative methods to get a reference of the button you have just clicked