# Simulate backspace in Vue Test Utils

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, mocha.js, vue-test-utils

I've written a standalone reusable component in VueJS that is essentially just a wrapper for an input field, but that does smart real-time processing of the keyboard input based on props passed to it.

It's working like a charm, and I'm able to successfully test most of its functionality via the Vue Test Utils (Mocha flavor) but I'm *also* trying to test that it correctly responds to special keys (arrows, backspace, tab, etc.) and getting stumped.

Here's an edited down version of the component itself:

```
<template>
    <input type="text" v-model="internalValue" :placeholder="placeholder"
       @keydown="keyDownHandler"/>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "LimitedTextArea",
        props: {
            fieldname: '',
            value: { type: String, default: ""},
            placeholder: 'placeholder',
            ...
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                internalValue: ''
            }
        },
        watch: {
            internalValue(newVal /*, oldVal*/ ) {
                this.$emit("input", this.fieldname, newVal);
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            ...
        },
        methods: {
            keyDownHandler(evt) {
                this.internalValue = this.value;
                if (!evt.metaKey && evt.keyCode >= 45) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    const inputChar = evt.key;
                    let newChar = '';
                    /* filtering logic here */
                    this.internalValue += newChar;
                } else {
                    // just for tracing this path during dev
                    console.log('will execute default action');
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

… and here's the test:

```
it('embedded: delete key functions normally', () => {
    const initialValue = '';
    const inputValue = 'omega';
    const outputValue = 'omeg';
    const deleteKeyEvent = {key: 'Backspace', keyCode: 8};
    const parent = mount({
        data: function() { return {
            textValue: initialValue
        }},
        template: \`<div>
           <limited-text-area :fieldname="'textValue'" :value="textValue" 
           @input="input"></limited-text-area>
        </div>`,
        components: { 'limited-text-area': LimitedTextArea },
        methods: {
            input(fieldname, value) {
                this[fieldname] = value;
            }
        }
    });
    const input = parent.find('input');
    typeStringIntoField(inputValue, input);

    // I've tried with and without this before sending the key event…
    input.element.focus();
    input.element.setSelectionRange(inputValue.length, inputValue.length);

    // I've tried doing it this way
    input.trigger('keydown', deleteKeyEvent);

    // And I've tried doing it this way, based on the Vue Test Utils guide 
    // for keyboard events
    input.trigger('keydown.up.backspace');
    expect(parent.vm.textValue).to.equal(outputValue);
});
```

Neither of the two approaches quoted above work. At this point I suspect that it may not be a simple question of calling the wrong method, and that I'm either:

1. misunderstanding the DOM within Vue Test Utils (effectively treating it like it's PhantomJS); or
2. using the wrong test methodology entirely for this case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you set the `.native` modifier like `@keydown.native= keyDownHandler `?

Comment: Hey, @brainbag… I've tried a few variations on that, and no progress. As stated above, the component is working as expected (including the delete functionality, etc.) , it's the *test* I can't get working. So I suspect the event handling is okay, and instead I'm banging my thick head against the Test Utils instead.

Comment: Thanks, @tony19. That really clarifies this situation. I'm taking your comment as an endorsement of "[I'm] misunderstanding the DOM within Vue Test Utils (effectively treating it like it's PhantomJS)." I like your workaround, but in this particular case I feel like I'd be 'testing the test.' I think I'm going to treat this as something that can't effectively be unit-tested, and leave it for an e2e test. Your comment could be reworded as an acceptable solution, hint hint.

Comment: @RiqueW Ok, done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simulating `BACKSPACE` on `<input>` natively (outside Vue in a browser) doesn't actually delete text, so I don't see it working with Vue. The solutions I found simply check the keydown event for backspace, and programmatically delete a character from the input's text [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32864842/6277151) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12040909/6277151). So, I'd say this isn't something that could be effectively unit-tested.

Note that [`vue-test-utils` uses JSDom (not PhantomJS)](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/choosing-a-test-runner.html#browser-environment).

Comment: Thank you, @tony19. I was barking up the wrong tree, what I was attempting is not applicable to unit testing with Vue Test Utils.